# Reset Mock object after first calling(Mockito, Junit)

Tags: junit, mockito

```
@Mock
MyTestClass testMock;

public void testMyTestMock() {
    when(testMock.function()).thenReturn(2).thenReturn(4);
}
```

How to reset mock **after first** calling?

Answer (score 0):

See [`mock.reset()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#reset-T...-) in the API docs

Comment: I know about reset(nameOfMock), I want reset mock after first calling

Comment: what would you be resetting?  Appending the 2nd `thenReturn()` is already effectively resetting the the altered behavior of the mock.

Comment: I know, but how a reset() mock after first calling yet. It's possible?

Comment: I was thinking there might theoretically be a way you could change the first `thenReturn()` into a`thenAnswer()` which resets the mock and then adds the 2nd `thenReturn()` before returning the first mocked value.  But I think in practice this won't work because all of the `thenX()`s have to run before you start using the mock.  But you could look into this